# Putty likes to print itself sometimes in my command line

Tags: c, putty

So, sometimes when I am programming in C through putty connected to a linux server, after executing my C file for testing, the command line will fill with the word "PuTTY" repeatedly 30 to 40 times. Sometimes it will display the word multiple times inside of my program.

Anyone else have a similar problem? I am also doing file I/O if that has anything to do with it.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

When PuTTY receives a Ctrl-E (character code 5), it outputs "PuTTY" (unless you've configured it to answer with something else).  Sounds like your program's outputting some binary stuff.  Whether that's intentional, i don't know.

Comment: You are correct, I am dealing with binary. Do you know how to configure putty to not do this?

Comment: There's an option under "Terminal" that says "Answerback to ^E:".  That's where you can tell it what to say when it sees that character.  I don't know if blanking out that option will cause it not to reply, but that seems to me the most reasonable outcome.  Dunno what else that will affect, though.  The best option, really, is just to stop outputting binary to the terminal.  :)  It causes all kinds of other problems anyway.