# Very weird PuTTY error. TAs can't figure it out

Tags: c++

This is my code for a connect-four game. I have working that runs and compiles, but when I choose to place a conenect-four piece in column 6 the PuTTY compiler will automatically place the word "PuTTY" in the command line when it asks again what column I want to place another piece. This only happens with the number 6 and only after I enter the first 6. I can delete the "PuTTY" that appears and enter 6 again and it works but "PuTTY" will once again appear in the command line. The Teacher Assitants and I are all lost.

```
 1 #include <iostream>
  2 #include <string>
  3 #include <cstdlib>
  4
  5 #define ROWS 6
  6 #define COLS 7
  7
  8 using namespace std;
  9
 10 void cout_pac(); // cout message "player one pick a color"
 11 int players_colors(char); // this function will check what color player 1 chose
 12 void cout_pc(int); // tells players what colors they are
 13 void cout_column1();
 14 char** underscores(char**);
 15 char** gameboard(char**);
 16 char** player1_game(int, int, char**);
 17 void cout_column2();
 18 char** player2_game(int, int, char**);
 19 int check_endgame(char**);
 20 int win_statement(int);
 21 void cout_playagain();
 22
 23 void cout_pac() {
 24     cout << "Player 1 which color do you want red or yellow? red (r) & yellow (y): ";
 25 }
 26
 27 int players_colors(char roy) {
 28     if (roy == 'r') {
 29         return 1;
 30     }
 31
 32     else {
 33         return 2;
 34     }
 35 }
 36
 37 void cout_pc(int color) {
 38     if (color == 1)
 39         cout << "Player one is red and player 2 is yellow!" << endl;
 40     if (color == 2)
 41         cout << "Player one is yellow and player 2 is red!" << endl;
 42 }
 43
 44 void cout_column1() {
 45     cout << "Player 1 which coloumn would like to put your piece in?: ";
 46 }
 47
 48 char** underscores(char** board) {
 49     for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
 50         for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++) {
 51             board[i][j] = ' ';
 52         }
 53     }
 54     return board;
 55 }
 56
 57 char** gameboard(char** array) {
 58     for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
 59         cout << "| ";
 60         for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++) {
 61             cout << array[i][j] << " | ";
 62         }
 63         cout << endl;
 64         cout << "-----------------------------" << endl;
 65     }
 66     return array;
 67 }
 68
 69 char** player1_game(int color, int column, char** array) {
 70     char j, c, r, y;
 71     j = column-1;
 72
 73     if (color == 1) {
 74         c = 'r';
 75     }
 76
 77     if (color == 2) {
 78         c = 'y';
 79     }
 80
 81     for (int i = ROWS-1; i >= 0; i--) {
 82         cout << "hey" << endl;
 83         if (array[i][j] == ' ') {
 84             array[i][j] = c;
 85             cout << i << j << endl;
 86             break;
 87         }
 88     }
 89     return array;
 90 }
 91
 92 void cout_column2() {
 93     cout << "Player 2 which column would you like to put your piece in?: ";
 94 }
 95
 96 char** player2_game(int color, int column, char** array) {
 97     char j, c, r, y;
 98     j = column-1;
 99
100     if (color == 1) {
101         c = 'y';
102     }
103
104     if (color == 2) {
105         c = 'r';
106     }
107 for (int i = ROWS-1; i >= 0; i--) {
108         cout << "hey 2" << endl;
109         if (array[i][j] == ' ') {
110             array[i][j] = c;
111             cout << i << j << endl;
112             break;
113         }
114     }
115     return array;
116 }
117
118 int check_endgame(char** array) {
119     int gameover = 1;
120     for (int i = ROWS-1; i >= 0; i--) {
121         for (int j = COLS-1; j >= 0; j--) {
122             if (array[i][j] == ' ') {
123                 gameover = 0;
124             }
125         }
126     }
127     return gameover;
128 }
129
130 int win_statement(int gameover) {
131     int game;
132     if (gameover == 0) {
133         game == 1;
134     }
135     if (gameover == 1) {
136         cout << "Game board has been filled, no one wins!" << endl;
137         game = 0;
138     }
139     if (gameover == 2) {
140         game = 0;
141     }
142     return game;
143 }
144
145 void cout_playagain() {
146     cout << "Would you like to play again? yes (1) no (0): " << endl;
147 }
148
149 int main() {
150     char** board = new char*[ROWS];
151     for (int i = 0; i < COLS; i++) {
152         board[i] = new char [COLS];
153     }   // creates a 6x7 array
154     char roy;
155     char** array; // player's choice of red or yellow, holds array board as just "array"
156     int color, column; // the color the player chose, which column they chose
157
158
159     cout_pac(); // cout message "player one pick a color"
160
161     cin >> roy; // player's choice of red or yellow
162
163     color = players_colors(roy); // this function will check what color player 1 chose
164     cout_pc(color); // tells players what colors they are
165
166     array = underscores(board); // fills board with underscores then returns board as "array"
167     array = gameboard(array); // turns array into a visual gameboard
168     cout_column1(); // asks player 1 to pick a column
169     cin >> column; // gets which column player wants
170
171     bool game;
172     while (game, color, column, array) {
173         int gameover;
174         array = player1_game(color, column, array); // takes in column and returns new array for player 1
175
176         gameboard(array); // prints game board after player 1 has added their piece
177         gameover = check_endgame(array); // checks if game board was filled without winning
178         game = win_statement(gameover); // checks all end game statuses and tells user how game was ended
179
180         cout_column2(); // asks player 2 for a column to put a piece in
181         cin >> column; // gets column number from player 2
182
183         array = player2_game(color, column, array); // takes in column from player 2 and returns new array for player 2
184
185         gameboard(array); // prints the game board after player 2 added their piece
186         check_endgame(array); // checks if gameboard was filled without winning
187         game = win_statement(gameover); //checks all end game statuses and tells user how game was ended
188
189         cout_column1();
190         cin >> column;
191
192     }
193     //cout_playagain(); // cout asks if user wants to play again yes or no
194     //cin >> again;
195
196
197
198
199     return 0;
200 }
201
```

here is what it looks like:

[image]

Comment: http://imgur.com/DhwyDOL here is a link to what it looks like. Again, the "PuTTY" in the command line is entered there automatically after I enter 6. I do not type it there.

Comment: Again, why downvote? If you don't want to answer it fine but really? Just move on and let someone elsel answer it. It's a legitimate question and I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Putty is an SSH Client for Windows - probably not part of the real problem. Given how many `*` and `**` you have in your code, I would suspect the problem is that you are messing up some of your pointer indirection, and randomly poking outside your memory. Try using `std::vector` instead.

Comment: `while (game, color, column, array)` is VERY confusing - what do you really think this does?

Comment: Thank you @MatsPetersson, I will try that.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but your question is of the form "why doesn't my code work?", which is generally frowned upon here, especially when it comes to scholarly pursuits. Have a look at [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask a question. If you can try to narrow your problem down to a few lines of code, I suspect you'll start to receive some good answers.

Comment: @MatsPetersson I was passing those values into the while loop. I am new to C++, is that not what I am supposed to do?

Comment: "passing values into a while loop" doesn't make any sense at all - what goes into the `(x)` in a while-loop is the condition to decide whether to enter the loop or not, `while(false)` will never enter, `while(true)` will always enter the loop [and loop forever], `while(cond)` will enter the loop if `cond` is non-zero/true, not enter if it's zero/false.

Comment: I would start by removing stuff from your code, and make a small part work at a time - and unless your teacher says that you have to do it exactly this way, do not use any pointers, just `std::vector`. I removed your `putty` tag - this problem, I guarantee, has nothing to do with `putty` in itself.

Comment: `game == 1;` is a comparison, not an assignment. Turn up your compiler warning level. If you are using GCC try building with `-pedantic -pedantic-errors -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wconversion` and watch the carnage.

Comment: This could indicate you've pressed a particular key, or tried to output a control character

Answer (score 2):

The `PuTTY` message appears when you output the control character whose ASCII value is `5`, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12876699/putty-likes-to-print-itself-sometimes-in-my-command-line).

You output this character from the `player1_game` function which you call with `column == 6`:

```
char** player1_game(int color, int column, char** array) {
    char j, c, r, y;
    j = column-1;
```

Now `j` is `5` and then later on you do:

```
    cout << i << j << endl;
```

Since `j` is a `char`, this outputs the character with ascii code `5`.  `5` is different to `'5'`.

To fix this you should declare `j` as `int` rather than `char`. `player2_game` has the same problem.  Didn't it seem odd to you that your output screens only show `i` when you tried to output both `i` and `j`?

---

Your code contains a lot of other weird things and mistakes. Try to enable all the warnings on your compiler if possible. Some problems are:

- `game == 1;` should be `game = 1;`
- `while (game, color, column, array)` is nonsense; it should be `while(1)` and you need to put a `break` statement inside your loop when a player wins the game. Currently if player 1 wins you just go straight on to ask for player 2's move anyway
- Your code is difficult to read because of magic numbers and use of pointers everywhere. If it's this hard to read it must be even harder for you to write it.
- You never use the return value in the second call to `check_endgame(array);`
- The separate player1,player2 functions could be combined to a single function which takes the player number as a parameter. You could have a variable indicating whose turn it is, instead of copy-pasting chunks of code (e.g. as inside the `while` loop).
- player1_game, player2_game should check that `column - 1` is not out of bounds before using it as array index
- The lines `cout_column1();` and `cin >> column;` occur before the loop and at the end of the loop; instead of this, put them at the start of the loop. It's always good to avoid code duplication, and copy-pasting (as you clearly did with player1_game and player2_game) is a sign that things are not quite right.
- A lot of functions return a `char **` unnecessarily and your code uses that return value which doesn't make much sense. Get rid of `char** array;` entirely and just use `board`, e.g.:

  ```
  underscores(board);
  gameboard(board);
  ```

Change all the functions returning `char **` to actually return `void`

Comment: "Your code is difficult to read because of magic numbers and use of pointers everywhere.
If it's this hard to read it must be even harder for you to write it."

I'd probably say that it's easier to write bizarre looking code than it is to read it.

Comment: @drglove well - maybe easy to write the first time, but when you come back to it the next day or when you're trying to debug it..